# fetching picklist records from sales force using soql

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to fetch picklist records from sales force using soql. My Table name is Industry__c its having a field called Industry_Group__c whose data type is picklist. How can I fetch the records of the Industry_group__c picklist.

I have tried the below queries but it did not work.

```
select Industry_Group__c  from Industry__c
```

Answer (score 5):

First get the `DurableId` from the `FieldDefinition`:

```
Select DurableId
From FieldDefinition
where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='Industry__c' 
and DataType = 'Picklist'
and DeveloperName = 'Industry_Group__c'
```

Then you can run the following query to get out the picklist values, replacing the `EntityParticleId` with the `DurableId` from the last query:

```
SELECT DurableId, EntityParticleId, IsActive, IsDefaultValue, Label, ValidFor, Value 
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticleId = 'Account.00N1a00000ZZSAS'
```

Answer (score 1):

or in one step...

```
SELECT Value,Label,IsActive
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Industry__c'
AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'Industry_Group__c'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the field is not accessible to user .. Please check the **field level security** whether it has a **read/Write access** to **system Administrator** and then try to access it..